# How to set auto expire time in plug in?

Tags: magento, plugins, extension-methods, add-on

In last few days, i was trying to make plug in for advance search to put it on my e-commerce site and its works good.

But today when i serf the internet, i just find out that [aheadworks](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-search.html#reviews-list) had also develop this type of plug in and they provide this plug in for limited period like 180 days or 360days. when the time of plugin cross this limit then this plugin automatically destroy from their client website.

so anyone tell me that how to set time limit or auto destroy type features in my plug in because i also want to sell my plugin in [magento-connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) with minimum cost?

thanx in advance...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a business model and not about specific programming related skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't supply it for a limited time. The dropdown you're looking at refers to the period of time that their support service is available for.

Comment: >ok i have understand this thing what you want to tell me.